# How to compile SpeechMe

Tags: qt, symbian, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, carbide

I am trying to compile the SpeechMe project: http://projects.developer.nokia.com/speechme/wiki so that I can use the voice recognition in another project I want to make.

I have followed all the instructions and downloaded the full sources of Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx and used them to add all the missing files to the Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx directories included in SpeechMe. I have compiled them all in the order the wiki says and they all returned: "***Build Complete" but it seems that they did not produce any output files?

I then tried compiling SpeechMe in Qt Creator but it gives me these three errors:

Here is the build log for all configurations: http://sdrv.ms/PxlD6r

Please help, I really don't understand why this is not working!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing Carbide should have created those 3 files when compiling but it didn't, any ideas why and what I can do to fix it?

Files must be created inside pocketsphinx tree but they shouldn't be placed in the required location. Most likely you need to find library files and put them into the required folder manually.

Another reason might be that you are compiled a debug version of pocketsphinx while the latest project is looking for a release version of the libraries.

Comment: I can't find them compiled anywhere? Not the dlls or dsos.

Comment: Check full pocketsphinx compilation log for details. Provide this log if you need better answer.

Comment: I have now added the build log but I am wondering if the fact that the README says it was compiles with: (debug) using GCCE (Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v0.8) makes any difference?

Comment: This is not a thing you need to share. Run "make clean" before make in order to get a proper build log with all opertions included. Share log file through a file sharing website (dropbox for example). Do not mess your question with it.

Comment: Sorry for the log wait but I have now uploaded the log and I would really appreciate if you had a look at it. Thanks!